# IOS - Dispatch Queue - timing issues

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to display a loader screen within an IOS app whilst loading in 4 separate data refresh feeds. Basically I would like to queue each feed and when all are complete navigate to the homepage - Here is my dispatch queue code -

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {


    [self loadFitnessPlan:[prefs valueForKey:@"customerUID"]];


    NSLog(@"Block1 End");
});

dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    // block2
    NSLog(@"Block2");
      [self loadMessages:nil customeruid:[prefs valueForKey:@"customerUID"] categoryuid:nil messageopen:0];

    NSLog(@"Block2 End");
});
dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    // block3
    NSLog(@"Block3");
    [self loadShopItems:nil clientuid:nil];

    NSLog(@"Block3 End");
});
dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    // block4
    NSLog(@"Block4");
    [self loadResources:nil restypeuid:nil];

    NSLog(@"Block4 End");
});


dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    // block5
   NSLog(@"HOPEFULLY WORKED");
 [self completedLoad];
});
```

The completedLoad method is as follows:

```
-(void)completedLoad{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


    SWRevealViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loadedArea"];
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

});
```

}

What happens is - if I remove the logic from completedload and add a NSlog it is the last thing that appears in the console - If I leave the above code in, it fires midway through the background data loading - doesn't make any sense at all to me!?  Any ideas?

Comment: That `NSLog` after all those dispatches would appear after all the downloads are done sounds highly suspicious. I'd suggest confirming that. In terms of why your `dispatch_group_notify` appears to be firing too quickly, I'd wager that's because your `loadMessages`, `loadShopItems` and/or your `loadResources` methods might be initiating tasks that are, themselves, asynchronous. We'd need some info about what those methods are doing (e.g. how, precisely, are they initiating the network requests) to advise you further.

Comment: Are the methods calls inside your `dispatch_group_async` synchronous or asynchronous? (e.g. `[self loadResources:nil restypeuid:nil];`)

Comment: cheers guys - 3 of the 4 are synchronous - the fitness plan method however is asynchronous - we will try and switch to make them all synchronous and see if that solves the issue - still doesn't make sense to me why the nslog comment will appear as expected though -(ie if i replace the push code with a simple nslog string) Also if I replace the viewcontroller push code with a simple nsalert it displays at the correct time - so its a real head scratcher!

Comment: @Dancer BTW, another approach is to make all of these asynchronous, do `dispatch_group_enter` for each before starting the task, and then have the completion logic do the necessary `dispatch_group_leave`. That way you enjoy `dispatch_group_t` functionality, while avoiding making your tasks synchronous.